# Questions on Chords in This Piece of Music

Tags: chord-theory, analysis

Could I ask for some help with this piece of music.   Please confirm if my understanding of the chords are correct:

1. The Gb in Measure 1 is a Neapolitan chord of F Major (Gb Bb D);
2. The composer than moved to cadential 6/4 of Bb Major (F Bb D) in Measure 2;
3. After that, to the dominant chord of F major (C E G) in Measure 3;
4. Continued to remain in the dominant chord of F major (C E G) in Measure 4;
5. This is followed by another Neapolitan chord (Gb) in the key of F Major in Measure 4 before moving to the dominant chord of Bb Major (F A C).

[image: Harmony exercise, cleaned up]

<sup>Original on clickthrough</sup>

Comment: I see no chords at all - it's for trumpet. And - it's someone's homework!

Comment: Have you tried singing the phrase? If not, I suggest doing that and using the chords that thus appear as a point of reference.

Comment: I’m pretty sure if a I6/4 chord isn’t followed by a V chord then it’s not a cadential 6/4.

Comment: @Tim As I understand it, the problems with "homework questions" are that they are often too broad, lack sufficient context, and of course that they reward 0 effort and "do the work for them." This shows plenty of effort, and there is a substantive analysis to discuss. The fact that it originated as homework rather than personal curiosity, to my mind, shouldn't affect its validity.

Comment: @AndyBonner - hence no vtc or dv from me..! Still seems like a question out of context, though.

Comment: Ask the person who assigned it to you to check your answers.

Answer (score 1):

The analysis is incorrect:

1. Neapolitan chords are generally used in minor, not major, and in either case, they are major chords (e.g., Gb - Bb - Db), not augmented (i.e., Gb - Bb - D).
2. A Neapolitan chord in a certain key is generally followed by the dominant chord in that key, not a C6/4 chord in a different one.
3. A C6/4 chord should be followed by the dominant of that same key, not a different one.

Plus a couple other suspect issues:

4. Having a Neapolitan chord on beat 4 in one measure and beat 3 in another suggests a very strange harmonic rhythm, so is probably incorrect.
5. Since the preceding question clearly includes seventh chords, it stands to reason this one does as well. For example, even if measure 4 begins on the dominant of F, the presence of Bb pretty clearly suggests it would be C7 not a simple triad.